# Conditional method chaining based on Option

Tags: scala

Recently I found myself writing either DB queries or simple `Seq` method chains which I would like to be dynamic based on user input, for instance:

```
def between(from: Option[DateTime], to: Option[DateTime]): Seq[MyObject] = {
    db.all() // let's say this returns Seq[MyObject]  
    /* Here I want to either restrict the upper/lower bounds with from/to if 
       they exist or take all the values otherwise */
}
```

If I were lazy I'd just go with:

```
def between(from: Option[DateTime], to: Option[DateTime]): Seq[MyObject] = {
    if(from.isEmpty && to.isEmpty) db.all()
    else if(from.isEmpty) db.all().filter(_.date <= to.get)
    else if(to.isEmpty) db.all().filter(_.date >= from.get)
    else db.all().filter(_.date >= from.get && _.date <= to.get)
}
```

Obviously `filter` is just an example, I have the same problem with for instance `take` when I want to take `n` elements or all based on Option.

But what if I have more Options passed? What would be the idiomatic way of doing this in Scala?

I can go with pattern matching, but that's not extremely different to `if/else`?

I could make several `vals` and do `from.map(...).getOrElse()` but that introduces temporary `vals` and again doesn't look that much better than `if/else`.

Are there any other tricks I could use?

Comment: Just a question before trying to answer : is there really a meaning to `between(None, Some(...)` or `between(None, None)` ? I don't think it has any obvious semantic and I don't know what I should expect to be returned as a user, so I wonder if this method makes sense at all

Comment: @Dici well yes as I tried showing in the example, `between(None, None)` will return all the objects, `between(None, Some(to))` will only put an *upper* bound, so all the objects that are older then `to`.

Comment: Yes that's the way you implemented it, but is it what anybody would expect ie is this a good API ?

Comment: @Dici yes it's much easier to use for my UI guys since they don't have to do any checks themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a good design to start with, because it violates the very meaning of the word `between`.

I would just have separate methods for each case, with clear semantics :

```
def between(from: DateTime, DateTime)
def after(from: DateTime)
def before(to: DateTime)
def anytime()
```

Otherwise, if you really want to keep it this way :

```
def between(from: Option[Date], to: Option[Date]) = {
 val datePredicate = (test: (Date,Date) => Boolean, date: Option[Date]) => (o: MyObject) => date.map(test(o.date, _)).getOrElse(true)
 val fromPredicate = datePredicate(_ >= _, from)
 val toPredicate = datePredicate(_ <= _, to)
 db.all().filter(x => fromPredicate(x) && toPredicate(x))
}
```

It is more general and extendable, but very obscure.

Comment: this actually kind of misses the point. First of all ok I can change the name (just came up with something for the sake of an example), secondly I like to have a single endpoint it's actually easier for my UI guys - they don't have to do any checks whether the user input something or not. How are those 4 methods different to if/else? I need to do the cheks somewhere. Last but not least it was supposed to be a generic question, what if I want to have different filtering options? Something where I pass X conditions wrapped in option? I would have to create a method for every possibility.

Comment: the other solution I like much more thanks will have a look at it ;-)

Comment: suggested name : "inInterval(lowerBound, upperBound)". Having one of the bound (or even both) missing sounds normal.

Comment: @DidierDupont using the concept of interval is a nice suggestion, in that case I would even create a small class to represent it

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I changed my answer, which was not quite correct. It should fix it.